How to add an array item inside array of objects of an object in react-redux toolkit?
I am trying to update the user object's blockedUsers array, while keeping other data not changed. user object can have blockedUsers array or not, it is not certain. In slice I have:
    reducers: { CHANGE_USER: (state, action) => {
      state.user.push(action.payload)
    },
   }

And in component, I am trying to update this way:
dispatch(CHANGE_USER({blockedUsers: [...user?.blockedUsers, selectedUser] }))

where selectedUser is an object: {id: "xxxx", name: "yyyy"}. But error comes:
Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:2). 
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator()] method.

Also, when I try this way:
dispatch(CHANGE_USER(blockedUsers?.selectedUser))

then, another Error:
ReferenceError: Property 'blockedUsers' doesn't exist

How can I solve this?

Can we see the code of the rest of the component? Along with what the object of user looks like

@justnut The code is very large, can you ask which information you need?

I don't really know what I need without seeing it? Not sure where the error could be coming from, but for now just the state object of user(its type definition) should help!

Can you at least show the current shape of the blockedUser object and what you want the shape to look like after you dispatch the change user action?

@HamedJimoh can you look @ new edits?

if you are trying to update the object user which has a property blockedUsers, why are you pushing onto the object? The first error looks to be coming from the blockedUsers being undefined, you can probably fix it by replacing [...users?.blockedUsers with [...(users?.blockedUsers || []).

@justnut again the same error (first error)

Can't really help without more information then :) Need to know more about the user looks like in the state and the component dispatching.

@justnut all info is written in question, user is an object having array of objects inside.

No one here can address issues in code they can't see. Please [edit] your post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, the complete error message and any accompanying stacktrace, and better details about what you have already tried or debugged. See the full [tour] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Why are you trying to apply some "reducer logic" in the forming of the action payload? Just dispatch the payload value you want to handle in the reducer, and apply the appropriate logic to update the state in the case reducer function.

@DrewReese Now, I ended up understanding why this happens, the problem was about retrieving objects of objects from backend and considering it as array. Thanks you all!

Try this i think this is happening cause you're directly spreading object in a array.
dispatch(CHANGE_USER({blockedUsers: [{...user?.blockedUsers, selectedUser}] }))

again the same error (non iterable error). Maybe better to make revision to slice action?

EDIT: state.user.push is not a function error now). Maybe better to make revision to slice action?

You forgot to share the link you wanted to reference.

If users is an object with a property blockedUsers, to update it you should be doing the following within the reducer
CHANGE_USER: (state, action) => {
 if(!action.payload) return;
 state.user = { 
  ...state.user, 
  blockedUsers = [
   ...(state.user.blockedUsers || []),
   ...action.payload ]
 };
}

This takes the existing user states and assures that it remains the same, and for the blockedUsers it will keep all the users that are already within the array and add whatever is in the payload.
The payload should now be something like this for this to work as expected
dispatch(CHANGE_USER(usersToBlock))

usersToBlock has to be an array, let me know if this causes any new errors.

You are using blockedUsers  directly inside reducer. I want to use this reducer to change also the other properties of user, not only blockedUsers  property. Can you edit your answer regarding this?

For what you want to achieve with keeping existing blockedUsers that will not work. You will need to create a separate reducer for this if it is the only one that requires this special treatment and leave the change_user reducer for all other properties. You could optionally add checks to see what the payload is and have it behave differently depending but its better practice to simply create more reducers than overcomplicate this one.
